# Stripe connect calculate application fee with a fixed fee in different currency

Tags: stripe-connect

In my application users can connect their stripe account.  Then for each transaction in connected account, the application fee is taking as 3% plus a fixed fee $1  of charge amount. ie 3% + 1$.

When a customer get charged,

```
Charge amount : $10
Application fee : 3% of 10 + $1
Here the application fee is calculated as (10*3/100) + 1  ie
$1.3



$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
   "amount" => 1000,
   "currency" => "usd",
   "source" => "tok_visa",
   "application_fee" => 130,
 ), array("stripe_account" => "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}"));*
```

The above will works well for usd. But for currency other than usd say for eg gbp ,  the correct value for application fee is $1.39

ie 10 gbp = 13.05 usd
 So fee = (13.05*3/100) + 1$ = $1.39

Here the fixed fee is in usd. So 3% should be calculated from the converted amount (gbp to usd) and then add the fixed fee of $1.

How can I set the correct application fee in this case?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has nice documentation explaining your use case in the following section.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/currencies#converting-balances

Also, check out there "example scenario" section.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/currencies#example-scenarios